# php implode two dimensional array and generate a string

Tags: php, sql, loops, foreach, implode

To insert multiple records at once in mysql, I want to first convert two dimensional array into a string and then fire mysql query in php to insert all those records,

I have two dimensional array as following,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ryan
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Simon
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )
    .
    .
    .
)
```

And I want to make a string like this,

```
('Ryan', '1', '0'), ('Simon', '2', '1'), .....
```

I know if it was one dimensional we can do it like, `"'" . implode("','", $row) . "'"`

Of course we can do it with foreach inside foreach loop. But i want to do it with implode function. Any idea ?

Comment: Only with implode functions? You will need at least something which cycles through all arrays

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to serialize the array or JSON encoding it ?

Comment: @Rizier123, I haven't explicitly mentioned "only with implode function". We most probably use other functions as well.

Comment: @SohanPatel Well then the you already know the solution kind of. You need somehow to cycle through all arrays and implode them

Answer (score 2):

Following code can be used for your problem to implode 2d array in to a string

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
 return "(".implode(',',$entry).")";
}, $inputArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of constructing an insert query with implode.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sii', $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: @SohanPatel prepared statements are actually ideal for queries that will be executed many times because the query is just parsed once

Comment: @FuzzyTree The only question would be now which API OP uses, maybe he already uses PDO or so. (But the answer alone is correct :)

Comment: @SohanPatel So where are we with this question? Is the answer from FuzzyTree what you want/need?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes I use PDO. But I have a question. Which is best way to use ? Should I generate query from loops and insert all records at once or as FuzzyTree suggested : using prepared statements. which one is better in terms of performance. Sorry I'm new in PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't do this only with `implode()` calls. You have to cycle through the array. But something like this should work for you:

```
<?php

    echo $str = "(" . implode("), (", array_map(function($v){
        return "'" . implode("','", $v) . "'";
    }, $row)) . ")";

?>
```